# unable to show localsearchresponse data in table view in ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, mklocalsearch

I am working on a app using `MapView` now have an issue kindly help me to figure out.

- I placed a search bar when user types the name of a place then it gives suggestions based upon the string entered.
- Using mapkit, I am able to send query to default maps, receive MKLocalSearchResponse.

> Now My problem is data from LocalSearchResponse is not getting displayed in **tableView cells**.

please kindly provide an solution.

**Using tools: Xcode 7.3, swift 2.2**

Here is my code kindly have a look.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDelegate {

var searchController:UISearchController!
var annotation:MKAnnotation!
var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
var items1:String = ""

var error:NSError!
var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!
var matchingItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()
var mapItems: [MKMapItem] = [MKMapItem]()
var itm : [String] = []

@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Place Not Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        for item in localSearchResponse!.mapItems {

            print("Name = \(item.name)")
            self.items1 = item.name!

            self.matchingItems.append(item as MKMapItem)
            print("Matching items = \(self.matchingItems.count)")
                }
        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)
    }

}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return matchingItems.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
let entry = matchingItems[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = items1[indexPath.row]

return cell
}
```

}

Comment: you didn't set uitableview delegate ?

Comment: Sorry for that, but even after adding UITableViewDelegate I am not able to display the LocalSearchResponse in table view cells.

Comment: just put a breakpoint in tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath function .check wthr it called or not

Comment: if that function called check matchingItems array has any value

Comment: tableview function cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting called! and yes the matchingItems do have an values because I am printing them and able to see the items.

Comment: Have you set dataSource for your tableView?

Comment: Even I tried adding self.tableView1.reloadData() after the data is received and viewdidappear.

Comment: Log tableView.dataSource and see whether it has been set.

Comment: I dontknow how to set dataSource for tableView. I will try it

Comment: the same way you set delegate. The datasource is responsible for the call of numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndex, etc. So if its nil then none of the dataSource methods wont get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set the `delegate` and `datasource` of your `tableView` to the associated `viewController` using the storyboard properly *see image*
2. Add delegate and datasuorce both seprating with comma like `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in your class.

[image]

> now you dont need to set the delegate inside the program.

- call reloadData() function each and everytime when you type a single word or accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way to clear the table view cells content every time user searches again and How to find whether user is typing or finished or canceled. I am using bar button item not search bar.

Comment: @GuruTeja you can detect user typing by using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` [**delegate method**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate--mobile-10943) of `uitextfield` ..

Comment: why cant we use  func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool.